# Is there a new automatic redirect for duplicate questions?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, duplicate-questions, redirection

I feel like this has happened to me several times today, though [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/232377/discrimination-against-100-years-old-people) is the only example I have saved a link for.

Recently, when I click on a question on a site's main page that's been marked [duplicate], I seem to be getting an auto-redirect to the original question. If this is intentional, I think it's sub-optimal. Not every question that gets closed as a duplicate is an accurate closure, and even if they were: if I want to view the duplicate why can't I? We've always been able to in the past, and this completely eliminates the ability for regular users to reopen (I assume mods on a given site wouldn't be redirected, as is true for other redirect functionality on SE).

So... Is something strange going on, or is this an intentional change? If so, what's the reasoning behind it, and can we please put it back the way it was?

Comment: Were you not logged in? Redirects are automatic for anonymous users

Comment: No repro while logged in, FWIW...

Comment: @mhlester Ahhhh. That's probably it; I've been having some weird behavior lately where I'll get randomly logged out of certain sites for no apparent reason, and have trouble logging back in (which did happen right before I went to post this question). I think that's probably the answer, if you want to post it as such.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Redirects are automatic for anonymous users, since there's very little value to the original link - they just want to see the best answer.

For logged in users, we know how to click through if we want the answer, and can help with moderating duties on the original page.

Answer (score -2):

Yes there's an automatic redirect for anonymous readers (not logged in). I don't like it. It's confusing to be taken to a different page than you saw in the search results, with potentially none of the words you searched for. (Duplicate questions are often better written—that's why they appear higher in the search results).

It's duplicitous to show different pages to search engine crawlers than to anonymous readers. This is one reason people dislike Quora.

Comment: This should be a new feature request, not answer to this question. (which makes it just a rant)

Comment: @ShadowWizard you're welcome to repost it.

Comment: Why should I? I do like the way it stands now, and don't want a change. I was just explaining my downvote.