# Question's link brings me to incorrect page

Tags: bug

I tried clicking on the top question's link on this page (Buying at a lower price [duplicate]): https://money.stackexchange.com/questions?page=1051&sort=votes

[image: screenshot]

However, when I click on it, it brings me to the wrong question. It brings me here:
[What is the final price if the bid price exceeds the ask price in an order driven market?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/52263/what-is-the-final-price-if-the-bid-price-exceeds-the-ask-price-in-an-order-drive)

Is this a weird bug, or am I really confused?

**EDIT:**

I tried going to the supposed poster's account ([Randy](https://money.stackexchange.com/users/49030/randy)). When I click on the question on his account (Buying at a lower price [duplicate]), it also brings me here: [What is the final price if the bid price exceeds the ask price in an order driven market?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/52263/what-is-the-final-price-if-the-bid-price-exceeds-the-ask-price-in-an-order-drive)

Comment: I think there's another question that explains this, so a quick comment while I look: Unauthenticated users get redirected to the dupe target, if a question with no answers is closed as duplicate. Not a bug, but a (admittedly jarring) feature.

Comment: [Here's the post where this feature was asked for and implemented](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125220/automatically-redirect-anonymous-user-from-unanswered-duplicate-question-to-corr) and [here's another post thinking this is a bug.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/232392/is-there-a-new-automatic-redirect-for-duplicate-questions)